# ProcessingJS as a js graphics library

Tags: javascript, processing

I encountered a problem when I was reading the page

http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html

Please note the section "Processing.js as javascript graphics library":

the setup method is rewrote as following:

```
pjs.setup = function() {
      pjs.size(200,200);
      // we want to turn off animation, because this is a demo page and it
      // would use cpu while not being looked at. Only draw on mousemoves
      pjs.noLoop();
    }
```

and Finally, we can call setup() to kickstart the sketch.

```
pjs.setup();
```

The question is that the setup() is already override, how can the processing run the loop? there's no such code to invoke draw() loop in setup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `draw()` method gets called automatically according to the value of a field called `doLoop` inside the Processing class (source code: https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/downloads/processing-js/processing-js/processing-1.4.1.js).

When you call `noLoop()` you are setting this value to false, disabling in fact the loop. If don't do this, then Processing.js behaves in its **default way** executing the loop: there's no need to state it explicitly in the `setup()` method.

Comment: Technically, what is the mechanism PJS used by just calling setup() to execute the loop? It seems to be implicit.

Comment: I don't know the technical details behind this, you should look at the code I linked in the answer. Anyway I assume Processingjs uses setInterval() to call the looping method every time. Also look at the function executeSketch inside that code, you might find it interesting.